# Issue with FB Login

Tags: ios, iphone, swift5

Hellos developers,
who anyone can help me with one issue , I try to make a Facebook login and after that I want to go to another view.
But I can't make that happens, could some one can help me with that?
I put my code below:

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
class ViewController: UIViewController , LoginButtonDelegate{
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result: LoginManagerLoginResult?, 
   error: Error?) {
    loginButton.permissions = ["public_profile","email"]
    if error != nil {
        print("Something is Wrong... \(String(describing: error))")
        return
    }
    print("Succesful loged in !")
}
func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton) {
    loginButton.titleLabel?.text = "Adios"
    print("GoodBye ")
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let loginButton = FBLoginButton()
    loginButton.center = view.center
    view.addSubview(loginButton)
    loginButton.permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
    loginButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getUserFBInfo), for: .touchUpOutside)
}
@objc func getUserFBInfo(){
    print("se logro ")
    let token = AccessToken.current
    if token == AccessToken.current {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondActivity", sender: self)
    }else if token!.isExpired{
        print("no sucede nada")
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `LoginButtonDelegate` to call your delegate function (e.g. `loginbutton:didCompleteWithResult:error:`), remember to assign the delegate to the `FBLoginButton`.

In the above code, since the delegate is the UIViewController itself (not a must), you will need to add `loginButton.delegate = self`